# JAXB: get tags from different levels of inheritance

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

How could I have with JAXB get all those 4 `<f>` tags from such an XML:

```
<f id='1' value='a'>
<f id='2' value='b'>
<table>
   <tr>
       <td>
           <f id='3' value='c'>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
<p>
    <f id='4' value='b'>
</p>
```

Is this possible at all with JAXB without creating classes for Tags for all types of inheritance? Or should I use different library for XML processing?

Comment: if all you need are the f tags and their attributes, then why not use the more simple XPath? or JSoup, since that looks to be HTML that you're processing.

Comment: I would like to have it already parsed to class instances

Comment: but actually i'm not sure if JAXB is proper tool for this case...

Comment: You can select the nodes with xpath, and use jaxb to bind these nodes to instances

Answer (score 0):

Solved with JSoup, getting necessary tags and manually putting it into necessary parents:

```
    Document parsedDoc = Jsoup.parse(xml, "", Parser.xmlParser());
    Elements fields = parsedDoc.getElementsByTag("f");
    for (Element fieldElement : fields) {
        Elements parents = fieldElement.parents();
        for (Element parent : parents) {
            if (parent.nodeName().equals("document")) {
                String id = parent.attr("id");
                // find necessary parent and add to it
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```